# I am facing error while runing sveltekit app (Not found:/)

Tags: frontend, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I am trying to run my sveltekit app, it was running fine few day's back but suddenly now when I run
"npm run build" it throw error Error: Not found: /, the way I understand is it is couldn't find entry file for app

// my vite.config file

```
// vite.config.js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
};

export default config;
```

// my package.json

```
{
    "name": "first-pwa",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "package": "vite package",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "playwright test",
        "lint": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --check --plugin-search-dir=. . && eslint --ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "format": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write --plugin-search-dir=. ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.21.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0-next.34",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^1.0.0-next.29",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0-next.314",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^3.4.1",
        "leaflet": "^1.8.0",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.7.0",
        "sass": "^1.50.0",
        "svelte": "^3.47.0",
        "svelte-leafletjs": "^0.9.0",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.6",
        "svelte-range-slider-pips": "^2.0.3",
        "svelte-simple-datatables": "^0.2.3",
        "vanillajs-datepicker": "^1.2.0",
        "vite": "^3.0.4"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@glidejs/glide": "^3.5.2",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.0.0-next.73",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",
        "bootswatch": "^5.1.3",
        "chartist": "^0.11.4",
        "popper": "^1.0.1",
        "svelte-loadable": "^2.0.1",
        "svelte-speedometer": "^1.1.0",
        "sveltestrap": "github:laxadev/sveltestrap",
        "ua-parser-js": "^1.0.2"
    }
}
```

I haven't migrated to the latest sveltekit changes yet I want my old app up running first,it would be very helpful if anyone could help me with this

I have tried adding entry path in vite.config.js but it didn't help

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: 'src/routes/index.svelte'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pages have been renamed from `index.svelte` to `+page.svelte`. When you rename  your routes they should be detected without a custom entry file configuration.